# Constant independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory

How can I prove this :

Let $X$, $Y$ be independent random variables and suppose $P(X +Y = α) = 1$, where $α$ is a constant.

Show that both $X$ and $Y$ are constant random variables.

Comment: If random variables $X,Y$ are discrete (i.e., they assume at most countably many values) you can write a straightforward proof using the partition of the probability space into events of the type $$\{X=\beta_i\text{ and }Y=\alpha-\beta_i\},$$ with $\beta_i=\beta_j\Leftrightarrow i=j$, and noting that $P[X=\beta_i]=P[Y=\alpha-\beta_i]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is *not* constant, such that for some set $A$ we have $$ 0 < P(X\in A) < 1$$
Then consider what the conditional probabilities $P(Y\in \alpha-A\mid X\in A)$ and $P(Y\in\alpha-A\mid X\notin A)$ must be, and see that this is not consistent with $X$ and $Y$ being independent.